# MDX CREATE MEMBER SYNTAX ERROR?

Tags: mdx

I'm very new to MDX, so sorry if this is a stupid question.

I'm creating a new calculated member

I'm getting a syntax error on Line 2 "AS SELECT NON EMPTY"?

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].FCR
AS SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Total Incident Count] } ON COLUMNS
FROM ( SELECT ( { [DIM INCIDENT].[First Call Resolution].&[Yes] } ) ON COLUMNS
FROM [ITSM Incident DM]) 
WHERE ( [DIM INCIDENT].[First Call Resolution].&[Yes] ), 
FORMAT_STRING = "Standard", 
VISIBLE = 1  ;
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put a Select statement in the expression of a calculated member.
You can fine more information on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146002.aspx).